# Can not access to GCP VM Instance via external IP although apache2 started

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache2

I've create an test vm instance on gcp:

- install apache2 and the service started success [apache2 started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzbSp.png)
- the firewall setup as default: [firewall setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAuio.png)
- the apache ports config: [port config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Df2k.png)
- external ip: [external ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNoM9.png)

it seems ok but I can not access via external ip as the document said https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp

Please give me some suggestions, thanks.

=================================

curl --head http://35.240.177.89/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.240.177.89 port 80: Operation timed out

curl --head https://35.240.177.89/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.240.177.89 port 443: Operation timed out

netstat -lntup:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woV4K.png)

Comment: Use the command `curl --head http://IP` and `curl --head https://IP`. Replace with your IP address. What are the results? Edit your question with each command and the output.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just updated the result

Comment: Add the output from this command: `netstat -lntup`. The output should show `LISTEN` for  port 80 and if you configured HTTPS port 443. Make sure they are listening on `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1`. If you have the correct listeners, then you have a firewall blocking access or you are specifying the wrong IP address. Make sure that the Linux firewall is either disabled or allowing port 80 and 443.

Comment: I just added the net stat result and the external IP image, it seems correct..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Linux has dual stack enabled, the netstat with `:::80` means that Apache2 is listening on both IPv4 and IPv6 port 80 for all network interfaces. You can check with the following command. A `0` value means that dual stack is enabled.

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only
```

Given the above, then most likely your system does not have an `iptables` rule allowing port 80. Assuming Ubuntu 18.04 (modify for your distribution):

Backup the `iptables` rules:

```
sudo iptables-save > iptables.backup
```

Allow ingress port 80:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Optionally allow ingress port 443:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```